# Truncated negative binomial distribution from age-binned population data

Tags: r, distribution, binning, fitdistrplus

I have data for two populations that are binned by age, with different bins for each population.

Age bins in population 1: 18-24, 25-29, 30-34, 35-45, 46-60, 61+

[image: distribution of population 1]

Age bins in population 2: 15-19, 20-24, 25-29, 30-34 ... 85-89, 90+

[image: distribution of population 2]

I want to infer a continuous distribution from these binned data in order to compare the two populations more directly. I tried fitting an untruncated negative binomial distribution but it was underestimating the lower bins:

[image: nbinom fit to pop 1]

So, now I want to try a truncated negative binomial distribution. I did the following:

```
library(truncdist)
library(fitdistrplus)

dtruncated_nbinom <- function(x) 
  dtrunc(x, "nbinom", a=18, b=100)
ptruncated_nbinom <- function(q) 
  ptrunc(q, "nbinom", a=18, b=100)

pop1_nbinom <- fitdistcens(pop1_dt, "truncated_nbinom")
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error in computing default starting values.
Error in manageparam(start.arg = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = pseudodata,  : 
  Error in start.arg.default(obs, distname) : 
  Unknown starting values for distribution truncated_nbinom.
```

Any advice on how to approach/resolve this?

Here's the pop 1 data:

```r
pop1 <- data.table(left = c(18,25,30,35,46,61), right = c(25,30,35,46,61,100), counts = c(2745,3115,2726,3433,1368,204))
pop1_dt <- pop1[rep(1:nrow(pop1), pop1[,counts]), .(left, right)]
```